# 'x' is not defined in custom decimal conversion function

Tags: python, undefined

```
def deci_to_any_list():
    n1 = input("Enter a number: ")
    n = int(n1)
    radix1 = input("Enter a radix: ")
    radix = int(radix1)
    converted_number = []
    if n>0:
        if 2<=radix<=16:
            while int(n/radix) == 0:
                converted_number.append(n % radix)
                converted_number.reverse()
                x = ''.join(str(i) for i in converted_number)
                x.replace('10', 'A')
                x.replace('11', 'B')
                x.replace('12', 'C')
                x.replace('13', 'D')
                x.replace('14', 'E')
                x.replace('15', 'F')
                x.replace('16', 'G')
            else:
                converted_number.append(n % radix)
        else:
            print("Wrong input!!")
    else:
        print("Wrong input!!")

    print("%d in base 10 is %d in base %d" % (n1,x,radix1))

deci_to_any_list()
```

```
Enter a number : 10
Enter a radix : 2
```

I want to create a decimal transformation function. I want to create this function using the append, reverse, join, and replace functions. If I type with the code above, it says name `'x' is not defined`. How should I handle this?

Comment: You should be replacing 10-16 with A-G in the list `converted_number`, not the string `x`.

Comment: Also you need to assign the result back to the variable: `x = x.replace('10', 'A')` because strings are immutable.

Comment: And that code shouldn't be in the loop.

Comment: Be more specific to your question. What exactly do you want the function to perform?

Comment: What specific error message are you getting? By providing the error message, people can see what line of the code is causing you problems. It makes it easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many inconsistencies in your code.

1. You are printing `x` without updating it.
2. python strings are immutable, once you `apply` replace you must catch the copy with another variable.
3. your logic for base conversion is also wrong.

The corrected code:

```
def replace_base(x):
    x = x.replace('10', 'A')
    x = x.replace('11', 'B')
    x = x.replace('12', 'C')
    x = x.replace('13', 'D')
    x = x.replace('14', 'E')
    x = x.replace('15', 'F')
    x = x.replace('16', 'G')
    return x

def deci_to_any_list():
    n1 = input("Enter a number: ")
    n = int(n1)
    radix1 = input("Enter a radix: ")
    radix = int(radix1)
    converted_number = []
    x = None # initialize
    if n>0:
        if 2<=radix<=16:
            while n>0:
                # conversion part
                converted_number.append(n % radix)
                n = n//radix

            # once the conversion is done
            converted_number.reverse()
            x = ''.join(replace_base(str(i)) for i in converted_number)

        else:
            print("Wrong input!!")
    else:
        print("Wrong input!!")
    print(converted_number)
    print(x)

deci_to_any_list()
```